# Access Soap based Web Service in Android

Tags: java, android, xml, parsing

I'm calling an webservice which is soap based in my Android application. It is returning me the XML response. How can I parse it? I checked the XML parsing its asking for the URL. I'm confused about which URL I need to pass?

Here is the code:

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);  request.addProperty("pStrType", type);

request.addProperty("pIntPageNo", PageNo) 

request.addProperty("pIntPageSize", PageSize);

           //Log.v(LOG_TAG," value:="+name);

           //Log.v(LOG_TAG," value:="+pass);
           SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = 
           new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
           envelope.dotNet = true;
           envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
           AndroidHttpTransport androidHttpTransport = new AndroidHttpTransport(URL);
           try
           {
           androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
           SoapObject resultstring = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn; 
           Log.v(LOG_TAG," value:="+resultstring);
           String Result=resultstring.toString();
```

What to do after this? I'm getting the string of response in (resultString).

Answer (score 2):

If you know how to use SAX XML Parser, you can convert the String into a byte stream and pass it to your handler.

```
    String result=resultstring.toString();
    SAXParser saxP = SAXParserFactory.newInstance().newSAXParser();
    ResponseHandler respH = new ResponseHandler();//your implementation
    saxP.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(result.getBytes()), respH);
```

If you don't know SAX parser, i would advice you to learn that first. It is simple.

Hope that helps.

Comment: HI ramp. can you pls tell me more.. m really having tough time using this.

Comment: Hi, As Ramp has suggested.. you need to use the SAXparser to parse the XML. His sample provided will be placed just below yours and you can use it..

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I am going to suggest product of my own company, but its a good suggestion for this question.

You need to get some sort of Code generator like [WSClient++](http://wsclient.neurospeech.com/wsclient/java-android-blackberry/)

Comment: Note that @Akash Kava is the founder of the company that developed WSClient++ according to his blog ("Akash Kava Founder of NeuroSpeech"). He has also been disingenuous regarding this fact in other posts about this software (claiming to have just "stumbled across" it). Please make it clear when you're advertising your own products.

Comment: Please disclose your affiliation in all posts where you mention your own product or risk having all of those posts removed.  Please read the policy in the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use HttpTransportSE instead of HttpTransport and use object instead of soapObject
try this code

```
  HttpTransportSE http = new HttpTransportSE("http://10.0.2.2:2612/Service1.svc");

  http.call("http://tempuri.org/IService1/GetCoursesInfos", envelope);

  Object result= (Object)envelope.getResponse();
  message=result.toString();
```

Check this code and tell me
This [post](http://ibraheemosama.wordpress.com/2012/05/09/android-and-ksoap/) tells you how to consume soap web service

Comment: if your problem with XML parsing tell Me